Dual functor in a rigid tensor category.
$\require{AMScd}$
Let $(\mathcal{C},\otimes)$ be a rigid tensor category in the sense of P. Deligne/J.S. Milne (https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/tc2022.pdf). On page $10$, they say that $$\text{Hom}(X,Y) \to \text{Hom}(Y^{\vee},X^{\vee}) \qquad \qquad(1)$$ is an isomorphism.
If one assumes that $(-)^{\vee}:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ yields an equivalence of categories, this is clear. But how would one show this without assuming that $(-)^{\vee}$ yields an equivalence of categories? Is there a chain of natural isomorphisms which gives us this?
Note that $(-)^{\vee}$ takes morphisms $f:X \to Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ to ${}^{t}f:Y^{\vee} \to X^{\vee}$, where ${}^{t}f$ is the unique morphism such that the following diagram commutes
$$
\begin{CD}
Y^{\vee} \otimes X @>{}^{t}f \otimes \text{id}_{X}>> X^{\vee} \otimes X\\
@VV \text{id}_{Y^{\vee}} \otimes fV @VV\text{ev}_X V \\
Y^{\vee} \otimes Y @>>\text{ev}_{Y}> \mathbf{1}.
\end{CD}
$$
Unless I am mistaken, it follows that if ${}^{t}f = {}^{t}g$ then $f = g$, so that the map in $(1)$ is atleast injective (I am in a bit of a hurry, and not feeling to well, hopefully I can update the post with a proof). I am more puzzled about how to show that $(1)$ is surjective.
I'd be happy for any suggestions/hints.

Dont they construct the bijection $\text{Hom}(X,Y) \to \text{Hom}(Y^{\vee},X^{\vee})$ via  a composition of isomorphisms? And taking the dual being an equivalence of categories follows from the definition of rigidity?

@Ben hi, can you give a reference for your first question? I looked it over (although I admit, not as thoroughly as I perhaps should have) last night and did not find any such chain of isomorphisms.

Regarding the second question, yes that is their claim. I want to confirm this for myself.

It is written on page 10 right under 1.7.2. Regarding the second question, taking duals is an equivalence because the natural morphism $X\to (X^\vee)^\vee$ is an isomorphism by Definition 1.7 (c).

@Ben but that is the internal hom, i.e. 1.7.2 is $\underline{\text{Hom}}(X,Y) \cong \underline{\text{Hom}}(Y^{\vee},X^{\vee})$. Why should that be the same as $(1)$ in my post? Perhaps it is, it was a while since I looked at this, I need to remind myself of the definitions. It is not immedietely obvious for me why, right now.

look at 1.6.4, applying $\mathrm{Hom}(1,-)$ where $1$ is a unit, gives then the desired bijection.

@Ben Oh yes, Ok, I understand, thanks a lot =).

Note that the dual of a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is given in terms of the duality data by: $$f^\vee = (\mathrm{ev}_Y \otimes \mathrm{id}_{X^\vee})\circ (\mathrm{id}_{Y^\vee} \otimes f \otimes \mathrm{id}_{X^\vee})\circ (\mathrm{id}_{Y^\vee} \otimes \mathrm{coev}_X): Y^\vee \rightarrow X^\vee$$ which gives the morphism you wrote at (1). To show that it is an isomorphism check that the following morphism is its inverse:
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Hom}(Y^\vee, X^\vee) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(X,Y)~,\quad g \mapsto \tilde{g} := (\mathrm{id}_{Y} \otimes \mathrm{ev}_X)\circ (\mathrm{id}_{Y} \otimes g \otimes \mathrm{id}_{X})\circ (\mathrm{coev}_Y \otimes \mathrm{id}_X) 
\end{equation}
It really follows from the rigidity axioms.
Side note: It might be beneficial to learn string diagrams. The above equations become more obvious.

A summary of my comments as an answer:
In a tensor category where all duals exists, the association
$$X \longmapsto X^\vee$$
can be extended into a contravariant functor
$$ (-)^{\vee}:\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}.$$
If the we assume that $\mathcal{C}$ is rigid, by Definition 1.7 c) every object $X \in \mathcal{C}$ is reflexive, ie. the natural map
$$X \longrightarrow (X^\vee)^\vee$$
is an isomorphism. Therefore $ (-)^{\vee}$ is an equivalence and the map
$$\mathrm{Hom}(X,Y)\longrightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(Y^\vee,X^\vee),f \longmapsto f^\vee$$
is a bijection.

I would write $X \mapsto (X^{\vee})^{\vee}$. I would rather argue that by the map just mentioned, we see that $(-)^{\vee}$ is essentially surjective. By the last part of what you wrote, we see that $(-)^{\vee}$ is fully faithful. It follows, assuming Axiom of Choice (see for example theorem 1.5.9 of Riehl:s "Category theory in context") that $(-)^{\vee}$ defines an equivalence of categories.

Although if it is the case that $i$ with components $i_{X}:X \to X^{\vee \vee}$ is a natural isomorphism, then I believe the first thing you wrote is enough. I am unsure whether it is natural.

Ops, no, right, I would write it as you did, i.e. $X \xrightarrow{;;;} (X^{\vee})^{\vee}$ (regarding the first part of my first comment).

@Ben123 the naturality is follows from the functorial definition of $i_X$. it corresponds to $\mathrm{ev}_X \circ \psi$, where $\psi$ is the commutativity restraint. I'm sure you can check that it is indeed natural.
